# How to insert JSX in Storybook control

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

Running Storybook I'd like to navigate to my component and play with Docs tab and check its behavior as I change control value for each property. I implemented a component Footer that could receive `string | JSX.Element | React.FunctionComponent` types (I'm using TypeScript along ReactJS).

Unfortunately, when I type `<div>my jsx</div>` inside control field, a red border comes up pointing error and doesn't update the component in the preview as expected.

This is the screen I'm trying to insert into control field:
[image]

In the `.stories.js` file I have at the end:

```
export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
    subscribe: "Replace me by the Subscribe component of Design System.",
    brand: <figure>Put branding logo here!</figure>,
    links: <div><div>first column of links</div><div>second column of links</div></div>,
    bottom: "All rights reserved."
}
```

The `Links` text is the default value for `link` property (from the actual React component file). As the code and image above can show us, it seems the JSX argument passed on `Default.args` in `.stories.js` file is completely ignored.

I'd like to insert a JSX into control field of storybook playground and then get Footer component live updated with JSX component rendered in the preview. How can I achieve that?

Comment: As of right now there is no way to do this. However you can look into [mapping for complex arg types](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args#mapping-to-complex-arg-values) which may be a good middle ground.

Answer (score 7):

I hope you find the answer till now, But I personally use the following config which is the items in a navbar:

```
const NavLink = () => (
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '16px', fontSize: '16px' }}>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
);

export default {
  title: 'common/Navbar',
  component: Navbar,
  argTypes: {
    children: {
      control: {
        type: 'select',
        options: ['empty', 'links'],
      },
      mapping: {
        empty: [],
        links: <NavLink />,
      },
    },
  },
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Navbar>;
```

It works for me!

Comment: I should try it in the project before vote in your answer and as the company I'm working for owns the project, and it's temporary paused, I need permission to make changes on it. As soon the project returns to activity I'll test it. Thank you any way!

Answer (score 0):

Some extra information here: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/docs/writing-stories/args.md#mapping-to-complex-arg-values

FYI, it works with booleans:

```
leftIcon: {
  control: { type: 'boolean' },
  mapping: { false: '', true: <PlusIcon /> },
},
```